# How to get active route react-navigation-5?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

I'm using react-navigation 5 in my react native app. In my app, I have several switchable screens like *Auth*, *Home*, *Onboarding* etc. In the Home page, I have a fully customized header & a nested navigator. In the nested navigator, I have 2 screens *List* & *Settings*. I want to display a gear icon in the header while displaying *List* screen and a home icon while displaying *Settings* Screen. For this, I want the currently active route name. How can I get the active nested route name from the Home page in react-navigation?

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@pratap2210/usenavigationstate see this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using nested navigations (stack > drawer > tabs) and i needed to reach current screen inside my custom drawer component so I use these for that:

```
const isKeyExistsOn = (o, k) => k.split(".").reduce((a, c) => a.hasOwnProperty(c) ? a[c] || 1 : false, Object.assign({}, o)) === false ? false : true;

const getScreenNameFromExactRoute = (exactRoute) => {
    var tmp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(exactRoute));
    while (true) {
        if (isKeyExistsOn(tmp, "params")) 
            tmp = tmp.params;
        else 
            return tmp.screen;
    }
}

const getCurrentScreen = (props) => {
    var lastscreen = props.state.history.filter(x => x.type === "route");
    lastscreen = lastscreen[(lastscreen.length - 1)];

    var exactRoute = props.state.routes.find(x => x.key === lastscreen.key);
    if (exactRoute.name === "MyTabsDrawerSceneKey") {
        if (!exactRoute.state)) {
            return getScreenNameFromExactRoute(exactRoute);
        } else 
            return getCurrentScreen(exactRoute);
    }
    else
        return exactRoute.name;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following method to listen for route changes.

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const prevGetStateForActionHomeStack = Stack.router.getStateForAction;

Stack.router.getStateForAction = (action, state) => {

 if (action.type === 'Navigation/NAVIGATE') {
  //Your code here, which will check for current route and process your business logic
 }

return prevGetStateForActionHomeStack(action, state);

}
```